I have this error when requesting quicenode: "{'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'non-array args'}, 'id': 0, 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}"
The following code is related to Ethereum network logs, which I am trying to extract with qouick node api. My code was working until a few days ago, but today when I visited it, I encountered this error:
{'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'non-array args'},
 'id': 0,
 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}

my code:
def get_logs(block_hash):
    logs_block = w3.eth.get_logs({'blockHash': block_hash})
    for log in logs_block:
        trx = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(log['transactionHash'])
        result = client.make_request("trace_transaction", trx['transactionHash'].hex())
        print(result)
get_logs('0xeadccd8a2436ab5d50736ae2f93998aa007d3115089c14733b9a5764f6c7caaf')
# number block = 20504126

My code shows the trx variable correctly and does not cause any problems, but when it reaches the result, it becomes a problem and an error occurs.
How can I fix this error?

I don't know this tracing API, but I see that the Nethermind API for trace_transaction has this specification:

Request
curl localhost:8545 \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": 0,
      "method": "trace_transaction",
      "params": [txHash]
   }'


...where the params property is expected to be an array with one transaction hash. Also the error object you quoted mentions "non-array args". So I would expect that you need to pass an array here:
result = client.make_request("trace_transaction",
                             [trx['transactionHash'].hex()])

Note the wrapping square brackets.

The error you're encountering indicates that the parameters you're passing to the trace_transaction method are not in the expected format. Adjust API call by modifying the client.make_request call to wrap the transaction hash in an array. Ensure that the transaction hash is formatted as a string and enclosed within an array, as JSON-RPC methods typically require parameters to be passed in an array.
adjusted code
def get_logs(block_hash): logs_block = w3.eth.get_logs({'blockHash': block_hash}) for log in logs_block: trx = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(log['transactionHash']) result = client.make_request("trace_transaction", [trx['transactionHash'].hex()]) print(result) get_logs('0xeadccd8a2436ab5d50736ae2f93998aa007d3115089c14733b9a5764f6c7caaf')
hope this helps
